# How to get response from Paynet.js load form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment-gateway, payment

I was trying to integrate Paynet.js for payment Integration They are having few custom HTML on page Load they are invoking below API on response I am getting session ID.

```
export function getPaymentSessionId(data) {

        data = JSON.stringify(data);

        let url = "/paynetj/auth?type=CF"
        let BASE = "https://pts-api.paynet.com.tr/v1"
        let actualurl = BASE + url;

        Api._callAPI(actualurl, 'POST', data, (type, dt) => {
            if (type == 'success') {

                dispatcher.dispatch({
                    type: 'SessionId',
                    data: dt,
                })



            }else{

            }

        });
    }
```

[ON page Load getting Session ID](https://pts-api.paynet.com.tr/v1/paynetj/auth?type=CF)

How to get that Session Id.

In the component I was calling action

```
let data1 = {  
                           token:"pbk_pcs_wCtr5nd31EhNm7DhjUarQpgxQasTb2pa",
                           amount:150000,
                           add_commission:false,
                           pos_type:5,
                           domain:"https://www.paynet.com.tr",
                           tds_required:false,
                           show_tds_error:true,
                           merge_option:false,
                           save_card:false
                        }
                        UserAction.getPaymentSessionId(data1);
```

Showing in response unAuthorized what ever the keys and values given in API doc the same i was sending, do i need to send that token from my end and what is that token, can anyone please explain.

Else Do i need to call same API from my Application, Is there any alternate to get Session Id from the API that is getting Invoked on Page Load

Comment: Can you share your code. It will be very helpful in helping you

Comment: Just i was researching,  On load of form itself automatically api is getting called, I need to get session_id from response, how can i get that.

Comment: @lomse
I have edited the question if you need any clarification let me know, i will explain